Woocommerce Unit (m²) Per Price for Variable Products / How to Display Square Meter Price for WooCommerce Product Variations?
I am working on a WooCommerce website where I sell products with different variations, such as 1kg and 3kg packages. Each package covers a different area in square meters (m²). I want to display the price per square meter for each variation on the single product page. For example, if a 1kg package covers 3.5m² and costs €15, I want to display "€15 (€4.29 / m²)" under the product price. Similarly, if a 3kg package covers 10m² and costs €30, I want to display "€30 (€3 / m²)".
I have tried various methods, including using hooks and filters in the functions.php file of my theme, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result. Can anyone provide guidance or code examples on how to implement this functionality effectively?
Note: I am using elementor single product template which replaces woocommerce base single product template.
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_square_meter_price', 15 );

function display_square_meter_price() {
    global $product;

    // Get the variations of the product
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // Iterate through the variations to find the price per square meter
    $square_meter_prices = array();
    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
        $variation_obj = wc_get_product($variation_id);
        $product_weight = $variation_obj->get_weight();
        if ($product_weight) {
            if ($product_weight == 1) {
                $square_meter_prices[$variation_id] = round($variation_obj->get_price() / 3.5, 2); // For 1kg package covering 3.5m²
            } elseif ($product_weight == 3) {
                $square_meter_prices[$variation_id] = round($variation_obj->get_price() / 10, 2); // For 3kg package covering 10m²
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the price per square meter
    if (!empty($square_meter_prices)) {
        echo '<p class="square-meter-price">Price per Square Meter:</p>';
        echo '<ul class="variation-square-meter-prices">';
        foreach ($square_meter_prices as $variation_id => $price) {
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title($variation_id) . ': ' . wc_price($price) . ' TL/m²</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}


How have you assigned the kg and m² - Is it ACF fields or?

Maybe this will help you to understand it better:

A product has 2 variation. 1Kg and 3Kg.

1Kg variation covering 3,5 sqm area. 3Kg covering 10 sqm area. I just need the customer can see how it cost as sqm when they choose a variation. Under or after price.
